# pgfplots: Positioning "node near coord" at the bottom of the bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I would like to position `nodes near coords` at the bottom of the corresponding bar, right by the X axis.

Here's what I've got now:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3}, enlarge x limits=0.15,
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-30}]        
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=3] {
                0   0.1872  0.0040  0
                1   0.0358  0.0017  22
                2   0.0358  0.0017  23
                3   0.0358  0.0017  24
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I assume if I could write something like `yshift=\getcurrentvalueofy` (or `yshift=\getbarheight`), the problem would be solved. I tried `\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}`, but I must admit I did not really understand what I was doing, so it did not work out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the value of the `y` coordinate available using the key `visualization depends on=y \as \rawy` (where `\rawy` is a macro name you choose). Then you can shift the nodes using `shift={(axis direction cs:0,-\rawy)}`. Note that you'll have to use `axis direction cs` because the coordinate system is shifted and scaled at the time when the nodes are placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
            symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3}, enlarge x limits=0.15,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                    font=\tiny,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:0,-\rawy)}
                }
        ]        
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=3] {
                0   0.1872  0.0040  0
                1   0.0358  0.0017  22
                2   0.0358  0.0017  23
                3   0.0358  0.0017  24
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jake can you please help me answer my question about stacked clustered bar chart. Thanks.