# How to put data labels next to the text labels in a bar plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to reproduce using PGFPlots the bottom-most graph found in this [link](http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/2012/09/some-finer-points-of-data-visualization.html):

[image]

The following is my best attempt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ytick={1,...,5},
    yticklabels={Barnes-Jewish,UCLA,UC San Francisco,John Hopkins,UCNI},
    xbar,
    title=Number of Verifications in 14 Specialty Areas of Neurological Care,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]

  \addplot coordinates {
    (13,5)
    (10,4)
    (9,3)
    (9,2)
    (2,1)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output is

[image: output of code]

The key difference which I am concerned about in this question is that the data labels are near the end of the bars in my graph, and are next to the text labels in the [link](http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/2012/09/some-finer-points-of-data-visualization.html). How do I put the data labels next to the text labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can borrow some of the code from [pgfplots: Positioning "node near coord" at the bottom of the bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110879/pgfplots-positioning-node-near-coord-at-the-bottom-of-the-bar) which does the same thing, except in the `y` direction.

The only new part I added was

```
    visualization depends on=x \as \rawx, 
        every node near coord/.append style={
        shift={(axis direction cs:-\rawx+0.8,0)}}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ytick={1,...,5},
            yticklabels={Barnes-Jewish,UCLA,UC San Francisco,John Hopkins,UCNI},
            xbar,
            title=Number of Verifications in 14 Specialty Areas of Neurological Care,
            nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            % begin new bit
            visualization depends on=x \as \rawx, 
            every node near coord/.append style={
                shift={(axis direction cs:-\rawx+0.8,0)}}
            % end new bit
        ]
        \addplot table {
            x y 
            13 5
            10 4
            9 3
            9 2
            2 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```