# "Node near coord" at the bottom of bar plots, but with symbolic coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I need to place the "node near coords" below the bars of a bar plot instead of above, similarly to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110879/74787) question, but with a difference.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
            symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d}, enlarge x limits=0.15,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                    font=\tiny,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:0,-\rawy)}
                }
        ]
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=3] {
                a   0.1872  0.0040  0
                b   0.0358  0.0017  22
                c   0.0358  0.0017  23
                d   0.0358  0.0017  24
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above snippet is exactly reported from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110887/74787) answer to that question, but with symbolic coordinates instead of numeric. Hence, the `0` in the shift x coordinate is wrong, and I get the following error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `0' has not been defined
with 'symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d}... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you m
ean something like [normalized]0?.
```

I tried to mess with `visualization depends on` but without success.
Is there a way to make this solution work with symbolic x coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest would be to use numbers for the x axis again by stating `x expr=\coordindex` which would directly work. To still have the "symbolic labels" just state them as `xticklabels`. (If you would have a **file** with the data it would even be simpler to "sync" the labels by using `xticklabels from table`.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        xticklabels={a,b,c,d},      % <-- changed
        xtick=data,                 % <-- added
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        every node near coord/.append style={
            font=\tiny,
            shift={(axis direction cs:0,-\rawy)}
        },
        nodes near coords,
        point meta=explicit,        % <-- (changed)
    ]
        \addplot table [
            header=false,           % <-- added
            x expr=\coordindex,     % <-- changed
            y index=1,
            meta index=3,
        ] {
                a   0.1872  0.0040  0
                b   0.0358  0.0017  22
                c   0.0358  0.0017  23
                d   0.0358  0.0017  24
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: works percectly!