# Increase distance of bars in bar chart in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\definecolor{trolleygrey}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.66, 0.66, 0.66}

\title{pgfplots}
\author{antonis.makris2411 Mak}
\date{July 2019}
\newcounter{cheat}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={
        -0.5*(int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth 
        + (int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1))*(#1))  +
          (.5+\plotnumofactualtype+int(\plotnumofactualtype/2))*\pgfplotbarwidth 
          + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
        },
    },
    A bar/.style={nodes near coords={\stepcounter{cheat}%
    \pgfmathparse{pow(10,int((1+\number\value{cheat})/2))}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},
      style={trolleygrey,fill=trolleygrey,mark=none},postaction={pattern=crosshatch
    dots}},
    B bar/.style={darkgray,fill=darkgray,mark=none}
}  
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Response Time (sec)},
        symbolic x coords={P1,P2},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.35,
        x tick label style={font=\Large,yshift=-10pt},
        y tick label style={font=\Large},
        y label style={font=\Large},
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={font=\Large,draw=none, legend columns=-1},
        visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
        every node near coord/.append style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110887/121799
                    anchor=north,xshift=0.2cm,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:P1,-\rawy)}
                }       
       ]

        \addplot[A bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 104.09) (P2,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 103.43) (P2,364.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
              coordinates {(P1,495.74) (P2,454.20)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 364.43) (P2,364.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
           coordinates {(P1,1929.74) (P2,454.20)};
        \addplot[B bar]
              coordinates {(P1,699.54) (P2,454.20)};

        \legend{S1, S2}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}% pic 1
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

that produces this:

[image]

This chunk of code:

```
\pgfplotsset{
        /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
            /pgf/bar shift={
            -0.5*(int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth 
            + (int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1))*(#1))  +
              (.5+\plotnumofactualtype+int(\plotnumofactualtype/2))*\pgfplotbarwidth 
              + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
            },
        }
```

sets the distance between pairs of bars  P1-10, P1-100, P1-1000.

Because I am new to pgfplots I dont know how to increase this distance. Which value to change?

Comment: I am not sure, which distance you want to increase.
Either: Between each of the two plots of one pair, e.g. 
 `P1-10 left and P1-10 right` or `P1-10 and P1-100 &P1-100 & P1-1000...`?

Comment: I recommend using plain TikZ only

Comment: Hello @oerpli. The second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this definition instead:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={
        - \distb * \dista * 0.5*(int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth
        + \distb          * (int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1))*(#1))
        + \distb * \dista * (.5+\plotnumofactualtype+int(\plotnumofactualtype/2))*\pgfplotbarwidth
        + \distb          * \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
        },
    },
```

It has two additional 'parameters' (actually globally defined macros), `distb` and `dista`.

Put this above the tikzpicture:

```
\def\dista{1.0}
\def\distb{1.0}
```

One increases the distance between the dark and lighter gray plot, the other between pairs of those. Find values for both that suit your preferences, as I am not quite sure, what you're going for.

I didn't get the `bar shift auto` function completely - my modified version is based on my (a bit limited) understanding.