# Descriptive nodes for certain shifted bars in bar plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

In the example below, I want a label node for each of the bars in the middle grouping. How can I get the labels to shift to right place the same way the bars are?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=First quarter comparison,
    width=5in,
    height=3in,
    ybar=0pt,
    xtick={2000, 2010, 2020},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ymin=0,
]

\pgfplotstableread{
   year   jan feb mar
   2000   3   2   3
   2010   4   5   5
   2020   2   2   1
}\mytable
\def\barcolor{blue}

\foreach \month [count=\n] in {Jan,Feb,Mar} {
    \edef\temp {
        \noexpand\addplot+ [draw=\barcolor, fill=\barcolor!20]
            table [x=year, y index=\n] {\noexpand\mytable};
        \noexpand\node [
            font=\noexpand\footnotesize,
            anchor=west,
            rotate=90,
        ] at (2010, 0) {\month};
    }
    \temp
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a `pgfplot`s specialist.

EDIT2

With `bar width=1` we can use 2009, 2010 and 2011 to place Jan, Feb and Mar

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675078/descriptive-nodes-for-certain-shifted-bars-in-bar-plot
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{month/.style={font=\footnotesize,anchor=west,rotate=90}}
\begin{axis}[
    title=First quarter comparison,
    width=5in,
    height=3in,
    ybar=0pt,
    bar width=1,%<-- ajout
    xtick={2000, 2010, 2020},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ymin=0,
]

\pgfplotstableread{
year   jan feb mar
2000   3   2   3
2010   4   5   5
2020   2   2   1
}\mytable

\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {
    \addplot+ table [y index=\i] \mytable;
    }

    \node [month] at (2009,0) {jan};
    \node [month] at (2010,0) {fev};
    \node [month] at (2011,0) {mar};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for getting me going. I should be to adapt your solution to bring the labels to the bottom as shown in this other [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110887/40803) and limit the labels to the middle group with some kind of expression or test.  But I'm still holding out hope for a more straightforward solution.

Comment: I did not see "the labels to the middle group", I edited my answer

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. (It's neat that you used the lowercase French months. Please don't change it.)